# How to avoid duplicate records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have three tables

```
1.Product
2.Category
3.Vendor
4.product_category
```

The same product will be in two category's but I want to show only one based on the vendor.

For example: 
Product table

```
vendor_id   | product_id    
---------|---------------
  1      | 1457          
  1      | 1457
```

product_category table

```
product_id | category_id
```

---

```
 1457      |  1
 1457      |  2
```

`product_id` 1457 will be in both category 1 & 2 but I want to show it only one time. How i can do it?

Comment: Do normalization. vendor should be vendor_id foreign key to vendor table

Comment: First, if your product can belong to more then one category you should use a many to many relationship by adding `productToCategory` table.
Second, if you have more then one rows for each product and vendor, How do you decide what row to keep?

Comment: GROUP BY, use MAX or MIN to chose which category.

Comment: If you want help with elimination of duplicates in the output, shouldn't you explain the output a little more? What exactly is the current query that produces the duplicates?

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response. i had done using max and group by

Answer (score 0):

I had done using Max and group by

select a.product_id,a.product_title,b.vendor_name,max(d.category_id)as category_id, max(d.category_name) as category_name from product as inner join vendor as b on a.vendor_id=b.vendor_id inner join product_category as c on a.product_id=c.product_id inner join category as d on c.category_id=d.category_id where a.vendor_id=1 group by a.product_id,a.product_title,b.vendor_name

Thanks

Thanigaivelan